# KML google earth <gx:Track><gx:coord> does not match <LineString><coordinates>

Tags: kml

[image]

I'm using KML and Google Earth to show spacecraft orbiting the earth with gx:Track gx:coord that seems to work fine.   I thought it would be cool to not only to show the crafts .dae model orbiting but also show the orbital path with a line.  So I'm using LineString and coordinates and that seems to work well too.   My problem is the line plotted with LineString/coordinates and the animated craft model path plotted with gx:Track/gx:coord are different.  They both use the same values, in the same order(done by C program).  They are both using relativeToGround for altitudeMode.

It appears that the model is running to the east a few hundred miles from the path here's my code.  What am I missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>  
        <name>orbit tracker</name>
       <Style id="yellowLine">
            <LineStyle>
               <color>7f00ffff</color>
               <width>4</width >
           </LineStyle>
       </Style>
        <Folder>    
            <name>intercept</name>  
            <open>1</open > 
            <StyleMap id="default"> 
                <Pair>  
                    <key>normal</key>   
                    <styleUrl>#default0</styleUrl>  
                </Pair> 
                <Pair>  
                    <key>highlight</key>    
                    <styleUrl>#hl</styleUrl>    
                </Pair> 
            </StyleMap> 
            <Style id="default0">   
                <IconStyle> 
                    <scale>0 </scale >  
               </IconStyle> 
               <LabelStyle> 
                   <scale>0 </scale >   
               </LabelStyle>
               <LineStyle>  
                   <width>0 </width >   
               </LineStyle> 
            </Style>    
            <Style id="hl"> 
                <IconStyle> 
                    <scale>0</scale >   
                </IconStyle>    
                <LabelStyle>    
                    <scale>0</scale >   
                </LabelStyle>   
                <LineStyle> 
                    <width>0</width >   
                </LineStyle>    
            </Style>    

                  <Placemark>
                      <name>relativeToGround</name>
                      <description>yellow path</description>
                      <styleUrl>#yellowLine</styleUrl>
                      <LineString>
<!--                      <extrude>1</extrude >
                           <tessellate>1</tessellate> -->
                           <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
                           <coordinates>
                                249.736573,-0.000023,376056.154875 
                                251.843021,3.145995,375522.230739 
                                253.963971,6.286935,375138.772855 
                                256.113750,9.417027,374905.321591 
                                258.307182,12.530269,374819.227168 
                                260.559828,15.620296,374875.733743 
                                262.888242,18.680247,375068.101533 
                                265.310220,21.702611,375387.764236 
                                267.845052,24.679046,375824.518196 
                                270.513739,27.600180,376366.739198 
                      </coordinates>
                      </LineString>
                  </Placemark>

            <Placemark> 
                <name>satellite_0</name>    
                    <Style id="default">    
                        <IconStyle> 
                           <scale>0</scale >    
                        </IconStyle>    
                        <LabelStyle>    
                            <scale>0</scale >   
                        </LabelStyle>   
                        <LineStyle> 
                            <width>0</width >   
                        </LineStyle>    
                    </Style>    
                    <styleUrl>#default</styleUrl>   
                    <gx:Track kml:id="ID_0">    
                        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
                        <when>2022-10-02T00:00:00</when>
                        <when>2022-10-02T00:01:00</when>
                        <when>2022-10-02T00:02:00</when>
                        <when>2022-10-02T00:03:00</when>
                        <when>2022-10-02T00:04:00</when>
                        <when>2022-10-02T00:05:00</when>
                        <when>2022-10-02T00:06:00</when>
                        <when>2022-10-02T00:07:00</when>
                        <when>2022-10-02T00:08:00</when>
                        <when>2022-10-02T00:09:00</when>
                        <gx:coord> 249.736573    -0.000023   376056.154875   </gx:coord>
                        <gx:coord> 251.843021    3.145995    375522.230739   </gx:coord>
                        <gx:coord> 253.963971    6.286935    375138.772855   </gx:coord>
                        <gx:coord> 256.113750    9.417027    374905.321591   </gx:coord>
                        <gx:coord> 258.307182    12.530269   374819.227168   </gx:coord>
                        <gx:coord> 260.559828    15.620296   374875.733743   </gx:coord>
                        <gx:coord> 262.888242    18.680247   375068.101533   </gx:coord>
                        <gx:coord> 265.310220    21.702611   375387.764236   </gx:coord>
                        <gx:coord> 267.845052    24.679046   375824.518196   </gx:coord>
                        <gx:coord> 270.513739    27.600180   376366.739198   </gx:coord>
                        <gx:angles>0 0 0</gx:angles>
                        <gx:angles>0 0 0</gx:angles>
                        <gx:angles>0 0 0</gx:angles>
                        <gx:angles>0 0 0</gx:angles>
                        <gx:angles>0 0 0</gx:angles>
                        <gx:angles>0 0 0</gx:angles>
                        <gx:angles>0 0 0</gx:angles>
                        <gx:angles>0 0 0</gx:angles>
                        <gx:angles>0 0 0</gx:angles>
                        <gx:angles>0 0 0</gx:angles>
                        <Model id="model_5">
                        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
                        <Location>
                        <longitude>-152.12475 </longitude >
                        <latitude>52.4241697 </latitude >
                        <altitude>321869 </altitude >
                        </Location>
                        <Orientation>
                        <heading>0 </heading >
                        <tilt>0 </tilt >
                        <roll>0 </roll >
                        </Orientation>
                        <Scale>
                        <x>30000.0000000</x>
                        <y>30000.0000000</y>
                        <z>30000.0000000</z>
                        </Scale>
                        <Link>                                                                                                                                                                                  
                        <href>_work/kml/test1/models/spacecraft.dae</href>
                            </Link>
                            <ResourceMap>
                            <Alias>                                                   <targetHref>/_work/C++/genkml/models/spacecraft/solarpanel.jpg</targetHref>
<sourceHref>spacecraft/solarpanel.jpg</sourceHref>
</Alias>
</ResourceMap>
</Model>
</gx:Track>
</Placemark>
</Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I figured it out.  My issue wasn't in the kml at all.  My issue was the .dae file I was using for my model was not centered on the origin.  Imported it into blender, reset the origin, and I'm good to go.